# Put Logo In Css Nav Bar

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to put a logo in my css navbar because I don't know how to put a logo in my css navbar. I have no clue on how to put the logo in the css navbar so it would be very nice if one of yall can help me out.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #222;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}

img {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/minecraft/a/ad/Bat.png?width=325">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to create a columnar structure and have the background on the parent. And then add the logo to the left and links to the right. The best way to do is to use the `<header>` and `<nav>` tags as they are really semantic.

Here's something you might find useful:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

/* Add these */
header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #666;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
}
/* End Add these */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  float: left;  /* Changed here. */
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}

img {
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <img src="https://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/minecraft/a/ad/Bat.png?width=325" />
  </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Also, I just changed the background colour from `#222` to `#666` to keep it websafe and also make the logo visible. Feel free to change it.

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that I hope will help you get you on the right track;

https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrw49mj/7/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li class="NavHeader"><a><img src="https://oyster.ignimgs.com/mediawiki/apis.ign.com/minecraft/a/ad/Bat.png?width=325"></a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
  margin: 0px;
 }

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0px auto;
 background: #222;
 padding: 0px;
}

li {
 float: right;
 font-size: 20px;
}

li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px 20px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

ul li a:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
 padding-bottom: 17px;
}

.NavHeader a img{
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 height: 70px;
 width: auto;
}

.NavHeader a:hover{
 border-bottom: none;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```